# function which make new file inside new directory python, i get the error that the system cannot find the path specified:'Python programs'

Tags: python, file, directory

```
import os
def new_directory(directory, filename):
    # Before creating a new directory, check to see if it already exists
    if not os.path.exists(directory):
        os.mkdir(directory)
        os.chdir(directory)
        file=open(filename,'w')
        file.close()
    else:
        os.chdir(directory)
        file=open(filename,'w')
        file.close()
    # Return the list of files in the new directory
    return os.listdir(directory)
print(new_directory("PythonPrograms", "script.py"))
```

Comment: At what point do you get the error? Can you provide the full traceback?

Answer (score 0):

After making or finding the existing directory you `os.chdir` to that directory. Now your current directory is `./PythonPrograms`. Later, when you `os.listdir(directory)`, you've already changed into that directory and are looking for `./PythonPrograms/PythonPrograms` which doesn't exist.

It is rarely a good idea to `os.chdir` - this type of mistake is too easy to make. Instead, just keep longer path names. I reworked the code a bit so that code in the if/else isn't repeated:

```
import os

def new_directory(directory, filename):
    # Before creating a new directory, check to see if it already exists
    if not os.path.exists(directory):
        os.mkdir(directory)
    filepath = os.path.join(directory, filename)
    with open(filepath,'w') as file:
        pass
    # Return the list of files in the new directory
    return os.listdir(directory)

print(new_directory("PythonPrograms", "script.py"))
```